# WPF Combobox SelectedValuePath?

Tags: wpf, combobox

How can i add selected value path to two items in the struct/class ? In the below example i want to add SelectedValuePath as Id1*Id2

```
this.cboXXX.ItemsSource = Employee;
this.cboXXX.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
*this.cboXXX.SelectedValuePath = "Id1" + "*" + "Id2";* ??


public struct Employee
{
   public int Id1;
   public int Id2;
   public string Name;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't because `SelectedValuePath` is the object property path. You could do this, though...

```
this.cboXXX.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
this.cboXXX.SelectedValuePath = "CombinedID";

public struct Employee
{
    public int _Id1;
    public int Id1 
    { 
        get {return _Id1;} 
        set
        {
            _Id1 = value;
            CombinedID = Id1 + "*" + Id2;
        } 
    }
    public int _Id2;
    public int Id2
    {
        get { return _Id1; }
        set
        {
            _Id1 = value;
            CombinedID = Id1 + "*" + Id2;
        }
    }

    public string CombinedID {get;set;}
    public string Name;
}
```